# Sending an amp (&) using a post with Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, xml, post, encoding

I am sending a post containing text, numbers and data. The numbers and data work fine, but I'm having problems with the text, since it may contain an ampersand (&). For example

```
page.php?text=Hello World & Space.
```

Now I found that the "&" is received by server, but read as if a new variable starts. So it sees (I think):

```
text = "Hello World "
Space. =
```

I did read that I could try to encode the text to make it look like it's a URL (like " " [space] turns into "%20") but there is no way to encode it properly. I came to the conclusion:

```
textToPOST = [text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But that does NOT encode the ampersands, but everything else. So the result is:

```
some text &uuml; blablabla
```

turns into

```
some%20text%20&uuml;%20blablabla
```

with the & not encoded. So how can I do this, please help.

Thanks a lot already

Comment: PS: I found a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-problem-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string answering the main question, but now I'm stuck on ...range:wholeString]; the wholeString NSRange apparently does not exist for Mac?

Comment: use `NSMakeRange(0, [escaped length])]` instead of `wholeString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for that answer and sorry for my premature posting :S I hope it at least helps anybody who has the same issue as I had. I just had a chat with a friend and he told me:

> To display and ampersand in XML simply use the &amp; quote. Unlike with a pure "&", the NSXMLParser won't output an error. Using &amp; also allows you to make other symbol escapes like:
>
> - ü [in text] -> &uuml; [in HTML] -> &amp;uuml; [in XML]
> - Ä [in text] -> &Auml; [in HTML] -> &amp;Auml; [in XML]
> - ß [in text] -> &szlig; [in HTML] -> &amp;szlig; [in XML]
> - etc...

So that's how you solve the "*How do I parse XML with an amp in it problem*". Also I managed to make the code, from the website I linked in a comment to my original question, work:

```
NSMutableString *deutschEscaped = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[deutschTextLabel string] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@"%24" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"%3B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"%40" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"%09" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"%23" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"%3C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"%3E" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%22" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
[deutschEscaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"%0A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [deutschEscaped length])];
```

This works fine for me and does replace ampersands and any other possible hazards.

If you don't want many %20 escapes for every space, you can also use:

```
NSMutableString *englishEscaped = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[englishTextLabel string] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is not URL-encoding as most people understand it. It escapes characters that are completely invalid to have in a URL, but not characters that have a special meaning in a URL. So it's usable for ‘correcting’ an invalid user-inputted URL, but it's quite unsuitable for creating a URL from escaped path and query string components.

(In JavaScript terms, it is analogous to `encodeURI` and not the one you need *far* more often which is `encodeURIComponent`.)

So to do it properly you will need another method, either your own or pinched from an existing framework (this is a very common sore point so many libraries have workarounds). It's possible to implement using [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917409/encoding-spaces-in-uitextview-uitextfield-to-url-format/4140183#4140183) for example code.