# PHP file_get_contents breaks up at &

Tags: php, file-get-contents

**SOLUTION**
Because objective-c doesn't encode & (because it is reserved) you should create your own method.
Source: [Sending an amp (&) using a post with Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888824/sending-an-amp-using-a-post-with-obj-c)

For my iOS and Android app I use a php script to get some data. This script has 1 argument which is a link. Basically that script looks like this:

```
$link= urlVariable('link'); 
$source = file_get_contents($link);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);

//Do stuff with the xml
```

But when I send a link with the & symbol it crashes on file_get_contents

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/xxxx/name_more_names_) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

but the full argument is

```
name_more_names_&_more_names_after_the_ampersand.file
```

I tried encoding the link before sending it to file_get_contents with no luck.

Also tried:

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
     $content = file_get_contents($fn);
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}
```

with the same results.

Does anybody know why it breaks at &? I'm no web developer but an app developer so excuse me for the lack of knowledge on this subject.

**EDIT**
Also tried this:

```
$link= urlVariable('link'); 
$encodedLink = urlencode($link);
$source = file_get_contents($encodedLink);
```

This is the result:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fxxxxx%2Fname_more_names_) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

**EDIT #2**

I found why my url stops at the & symbol. I retrieve my argument from the url with this method:

```
    function  urlVariable($pVariableName)
    {
        if (isset ($_GET[$pVariableName]))   
        {
            $lVariable = $_GET[$pVariableName];
        }
        else
        {
            $lVariable = null;
        }
        return $lVariable;
    }
```

and _GET() separates arguments with the & symbol right?

Comment: already tried that. no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL should have its ampersands properly encoded:

```
https://www.example.com/xxxx/name_more_names_%26_more_names_after_the_ampersand.file
```

In PHP you can encode the path like this:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = substr_replace($url, '/' . urlencode(substr($path, 1)), strpos($url, $path), strlen($path));
```

**Update**

If you also have a tree structure, you would need to do more work:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$newpath = '/' . str_replace('%2F', '/', urlencode(substr($path, 1)));

$url = substr_replace($url, $newpath, strpos($url, $path), strlen($path));
```

**Update 2**

If your script is called like `script?link=<some-url>`, you need to make sure the `<some-url>` is properly encoded too:

```
script?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fxxxxx%2Fname_more_names_%26_more_names_after_the_ampersand.file
```

Comment: and how do I programmatically encode ampersands in php? urlencode() isnt the method I'm looking for. Nor is utf_encode();

Comment: @MarkMolina Well, I've added an example how to encode just the path, hope that helps.

Comment: I've found the problem... I use GET to grab my link from the url and thats where my url gets broken in two.

Comment: @MarkMolina What do you mean by "use GET"?

Comment: So is your script called with `?link=<some-url-here>`?

Comment: Yes thats what i was doing

Comment: @MarkMolina Then, you need to urlencode the whole url in the code that calls your php script.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$url = urlencode($url);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```