# iOS 5 simplest way to send email from an app

Tags: iphone, ios, email, nsstring

I just tried to send email using this code and it seems to work:

```
NSString* urlEmail = [NSString stringWithString: @"mailto:foo@example.com?cc=bar@example.com&subject=test%20from%20me!&body=this%20is%20a%20test!"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlEmail]];
```

The only problem is, is there a function I can use to automatically escape everything in a normal NSString so I don't have to write it out manually like this?  If not, how can I use stringWithFormat without conflicting with the % signs already in the string?  I basically want to be able to append to, subject, body, etc. dynamically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use MFMailComposeViewController:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setToRecipients:recipients];
[picker setSubject:subject];
[picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Comment: this method is really much more reliable

Comment: what do I need to add to gain access to MFMailComposeViewController?

Comment: MessageUI.framewor is not supported by iOS 5. How to do that if there is any other way?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/917630/535632, you can escape like this:

```
NSString *urlStr = [urlEmail stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Also, this answer (same question) shows handling of additional characters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4140183/535632